# Step3 in deal.II - Convergence of the mean

Tags: finite-element, convergence, poisson, deal.ii

I'm trying to understand the *Convergence of the mean* part of the [Step-3 tutorial](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_3.html#Possibilitiesforextensions) in deal.II. The authors say that $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega} u_h(x)dx$ converges with $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$, but I really can't understand the following sentence:

*"Again, the difference between two adjacent values goes down by about a factor of four, indicating convergence as $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$"*

- What do the developers mean with $h$? Of course it's related to the spacing, but I cannot understand how.
- Why does the fact that the difference between two adjacent values goes down by a factor of $4$ implies that the order of convergence is $2$?

---

**EDIT:**

Changing the degree of the polynomials to $2$, i.e. by setting in the constructor `fe(2)`instead of `fe(1)`, the mean values are:

$$1.139601139601139$$
$$1.140473273027236$$
$$1.140568088078042$$
$$1.140576306709475$$
$$1.140576961327481$$
$$1.140577011018993$$
$$1.14057701467338$$
$$1.14057701493724$$
$$$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$h$ is a measure of the mesh size. In the example, they are using rectangular elements. For which a commonly used measure of the mesh size is the length of the largest diagonal.

Looking at the table above the sentence you quoted:
$(M_5-M_6)/(M_4-M_5)=(0.14052586 −0.14056422)/(0.14037251−0.14052586)\approx 1/4 = (h_6/h_5)^2$
where $M_i$ is the mean at $i$-th refinement level, and $h_i$ is the mesh size at $i$-th refinement level. Since they are uniformly refining the mesh $h_{i+1}/h_i = 1/2$ for any $i$.

Letting $M = \lim_{i\to\infty} M_i$, you can now say that $|M-M_i| = Ch_i^2 = O(h^2)$.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing: they say in the last part of the tutorial that one could try with an L-shaped domain, too. If I solve the Poisson equation on an L-shaped domain, with Dirichlet boundary conditions, what is the expected rate of convergence?

Comment: It depends on the boundary conditions, but for some choices (see, for example, the LSingularityFunction class) the solution is not smooth and the expected convergence rate will be lower.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth for the comment. That functions is the solution for Dirichlet homogeneous boundary conditions and $f=1$, right?

Comment: @bobinthebox No, the set up is more complicated to get that function. But you're right that if you do $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ and $f=1$, then you also get a function with a singularity.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth .  I tried to change the degree of the polynomials to $2$, i.e. `fe(2)` in the `Step3` constructor. Each time the difference between two different value goes down by a factor of roughly 10. So I'd. say it converges with $O(h^5)$, is that correct? (see the edit for the values)

Comment: @bobinthebox No. If it were a factor of 8, it would be $O(h^3)$.

Comment: I agree with you, but what I observe is a factor of roughly $10$. Does this mean that I have to change also something else in the code to see $O(h^3)$? In practice I only changed the `fe(2)` in the constructor of Step3, nothing else. @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: The question is what the rate is *asymptotically*. What happens to the factor of 10 if you continue with mesh refinement steps several more times?

Comment: I edited my post with the mean values obtained using more refinements. That factor is slightly increasing, for instance $$\frac{1.140577014672688-1.140577011018506 }{1.140577014926523 -1.140577014672688}\approx 14$$ @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: Maybe, the quadrature rule is not of the correct degree? Try replacing QGauss<2>(fe.degree + 1) with QGauss<2>(2*fe.degree + 1),

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas You're right, I didn't update the quadrature rule. I updated it in the `compute_mean_value` and in the `assemble_system()` method. I reported the mean values in the post, but nothing changes actually. What's going on? I can't really find a possible bug here

Comment: You've reached the limits of accuracy. Your answer is already correct to 9 digits at the end, that's for all purposes exact. It doesn't make sense to try and infer convergence rates from such accurate numbers any more.